# Specify different appSettings per location in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, appsettings

I would like to have certain app settings values for all pages except in ~/admin. Instead I would like a different set of app settings. Is this possible with the location element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `<location>` method doesn't seem to work in 4.0 / IIS8, regardless of there being an additional `web.config` applying to the same path.

You could apply all the common settings in the main `web.config`, and then place another `web.config` in the subfolder (~/admin), and put something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <clear />
        <add key="foo" value="bar" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

If you don't use `<clear />`, you can allow the other settings to apply, but you can override any that you like.